# Does va_copy() require va_end()?

Tags: c, c99

When dealing with variable arguments, is it just `va_start()` that needs a matching `va_end()` call, or does `va_copy()` require a matching `va_end()` too, i.e

```
void foo(char *x, ...)
{
  va_list l,c;

  va_start(l,x);
  va_copy(c,l);

  ---
  va_end(c); //is this correct ?
  va_end(l);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, every copy and the original, requires `va_end()` to be called. Your example is correct, the order of your `va_end()` calls can be reversed.

From *ISO/IEC 9899:201x*:

> 7.16.1.3 The va_end macro
>
> The va_end macro facilitates a normal return from the function whose variable
>   argument list was referred to by the expansion of the va_start macro, or the function
>   containing the expansion of the va_copy macro, that initialized the va_list ap. The
>   va_end macro may modify ap so that it is no longer usable (without being reinitialized
>   by the va_start or va_copy macro). If there is no corresponding invocation of the
>   va_start or va_copy macro, or if the va_end macro is not invoked before the
>   return, the behavior is undefined.

The last sentence states that every `va_start` or `va_copy` must be accompanied by an `va_end` before returning.